# Acumatica web service API Login Failure

Tags: acumatica

I got the following exception when I was trying to use Acumatica web service API.Any help will be appreciate it.

```
System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: 
The request element <Login xmlns='http://www.acumatica.com/typed/'> was not recognized. at System.Web.Services.Protocols.Soap11ServerProtocolHelper.RouteRequest()
```

Comment: Which web service are you trying to use? How did you get the URL and the client code?

Answer (score 0):

Can you update this with a sample of your login code? **NOTE: Replace your username and pass with dummy data**

It would also be incredibly useful to know what language you were using to access the web service (C# php etc etc)

It should look like (assuming you are using C#)

```
try
        {
            LoginResult loginResult = context.Login("username@yourcompany", "yourpassword");
            if (loginResult.Code != ErrorCode.OK)
            {
                throw new Exception(loginResult.Message);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            Console.ReadLine();
            return;
        }
```

Comment: Have you generated the web service url within acumatica?